# Does the Anti-Kickback Statute apply to remunerations when a patient has private insurance?

Tags: united-states, insurance, health-insurance

The [Stark Law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/1395nn) (42 U.S.C. § 1395nn) and the [Anti-Kickback Statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/1320a-7b) (AKS) (42 U.S.C. § 1320a-7b) are pretty clear that they only apply to federal/state-funded insurance plans. Under these plans, a doctor giving a gift card to a patient when they refer someone to their practice is likely a no-no.

However, it sounds like these limitations don't apply to patients on private insurance, so a doctor could pay their patients to refer someone without running afoul of these laws.

My question is this: if a doctor accepts both private and federal/state-funded insurance plans, can they offer/advertise certain incentives, like a gift card for a referral, to patients that carry private insurance and not to patients on government-funded insurance? If so, do private insurance payers typically have any regulations/terms that prevent this kind of activity?